# CheckBox Validation in javascript failing for single checkbox

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation, checkbox

I have checkboxes created dynamically on the JSP page as follows

```
<form name="CancelForm" onsubmit="return validate();" action="ServletCancel" method="post">                  
<%   
for(int index=0 ; index<lstID.size() ; index++)
{
     String strBookingID = lstID.get(index);
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="BookingID" value="<%=strBookingID%>">
<%
}%>
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="button1"/>
</form>
```

For validating same I have the below JavaScript code to validate that atleast one Checkbox in the Form is checked, if so it should return "true" else "false" with an alert to check atleast one option.

```
function validate() { 
    var flag = "false";
    var CHKBBookingID = document.CancelForm.BookingID;

    alert("length of checkboxes >> "+CHKBBookingID.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < CHKBBookingID.length ; i++) { 
        if (CHKBBookingID[i].checked == true) { 
            flag = "true";
        } 
    }    
    if(flag == "false"){
        alert("You have not selected any passenger yet!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This validation is working Perfectly fine if I have 2 or more Checkboxes in the form.
But on the other hand if I have only one Checkbox the validation alert shows the "Length" of Checkbox as "undefined" as well as fails even though the only Checkbox on the form is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var CHKBBookingID = document.CancelForm.BookingID;
```

Causes the problem. if you are naming it as `var` it is considered as the variable , as you pass a single element.

so you need to initialize the `javascript` array as ,

```
var CHKBBookingID = Array(document.CancelForm.BookingID)
```

will input them into the array

[Learn More. .](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/creatingarrays.htm)

Update:

Using `jquery` you can easily get the number of checkboxes,

```
var CHKBBookingID = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='BookingID[]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
  // or you can do something to the actual checked checkboxes by working directly with  'this'
  // something like $(this).hide() (only something useful, probably) :P
});
```

Comment: It would sound funny but now it isn't working for more than 1 checkbox... irrespective of whatever the number of checkbox is it shows the length as 1 and fails if more than 1 checkbox is present and checked